# NLog how to log messages to console with different JSON layout formats in different scenarios

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, nlog

We are working with NLog. we need to log messages to console with different JSON formats in different scenarios.

**Ex: If exception occurred** Below is the format

```
{
            “id”:”5656”,
            “uuid”:”xdd895-65454”,
            “key”:”somekeyname”,
            “message”: “** exception message **”,
            “stack_trace”: “”**exception stack trace**”
}
```

**If Normal log message**

```
{
            "id":"8898998"
            “messge”: “Time taken to retrieve data from database”
            “Time”: “1100” (in milli seconds)
}
```

Like this we have 10 scenarios.

**Approach 1:**
I tried creating different targets in web.config file in nlog section as follows

```
 <target xsi:type="Console" name="console_exception" >
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="id" layout="${mdlc:itemid}" />
      <attribute name="uuid" layout="${mdlc:item=uuid}" />
      <attribute name="loglevel" layout="${level}" />
      <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date}" />
      <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
  </target>
  <target xsi:type="Console" name="console_databaseTimeTaken" >
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="id" layout="${mdlc:item=id}" />
      <attribute name ="custommessage" layout="Time taken to retrieve data from database"/>
      <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date}" />
      <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
  </target>
  <rules>
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo ="console"/>
</rules>
```

I do not know how to set the target and layout programmatically. 
So far I have found conditional based logging but, that is not a good approach.

**Approach 2:**
When logging the message we manually format the string message as per the need and then calling the log method

```
string logmessag= string.Format("\"id\":\"{0}\",\"messge\": {1}\"\",\"Time\": \"{2}(in milli seconds)\"", id, message, time);
```

Technologies used: Webapi2, Nlog 4.0.3
IDE: VS2017
Let us know the best approach to solve this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: The NLog JsonLayout will automatically exclude Json-Attributes where the result-value becomes blank. Maybe you can use this https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer (Ex. `length('${exception}') > 0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use filters, either on `<logger>` elements directly, or a child [`<filters>` config element](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages) which allows more complex conditions.

Eg. (assuming you can use the logger's name):

```
<rules>
  <logger name='DB' minLevel="Trace" writeTo="console_databaseTimeTaken" final="true" />
  <logger name='Error' minLevel="Trace" writeTo="console_exception" final="true" />
  …
</rules>
```

[`<filter>` elements](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages) allow more flexibility, but are still fairly limited. Ultimately you can extend NLog with [custom conditions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Filter#extensibility).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. you saved my day (pray). Is there any other best alternative?